# What kavanah should you have during *Atah Kadosh*?

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, kavana-concentration, kedusha-prayer, kedusha-holiness

The third blessing of the amidah, Atah Kadosh, seems mysterious to me:

> You are holy and your name is holy, and the holy ones bless you all day.   Blessed are you Hashem, the Holy God.

Is there any particular kavanah that one one should be having while reciting this blessing? We know that God is holy but how is mentioning that a prayer and what significance does it have within the amidah?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ran in his derashos, as well as the Kuzari, both explain the intent of the third blessing as follows:

In the first two blessings, we focus on how Hashem is involved in this world, and in our lives, and does kindness towards us. We describe the *middos* of Hashem in how He relates to this world. One may incorrectly associate this with being descriptive of Hashem's essence. Therefore, before moving on to the request section of the Shemoneh Esrei, we declare that Hashem is *kadosh*, entirely separate and beyond our understanding. This is the intent that one should have, understanding that Hashem is, after all our attempts to relate to Him and understand Him, ultimately beyond our understanding.

Answer (score 5):

The Amidah is divided up into 3 main sections. The first section, consisting of the first three *berachot* is called *shevach* (praise). The middle 13 *berachot* are called *bakasha* (request).  The final 3 *berachot* are called *hoda'ah* (thanks).

The *beracha* of *ata kadosh* is part of the *shevach* section (not the *bakasha* section), so if your definition of the word "prayer" is "request," then the answer to your question, "[H]ow is mentioning that a prayer?" is, "it's not."

I have heard the idea that the reason we put praise before request is because it is improper to approach God and immediately start asking for things. Instead, we start by praising him *and then* we proceed with our requests. I will attempt to find a source for this idea.

Comment: In the first blessing you bring about the merits of the fore-fathers, in the second you mention G-d's promise to revive the dead and other ways he benefits man. What is being achieved through the third blessing?

Comment: @AniYodea Mentioning his holiness.

Comment: I was aware of this idea but wasn't sure how exactly attributing G-d's holiness is in any way a praise since holy just means "spiritual" so G-d by definition is holy and therefore this blessing just seems to say "G-d is G-d"...

Comment: @AniYodea re your last comment: see http://mi.yodeya.com/q/2271

Answer (score 0):

According to [Beurei Hatefilah](http://beureihatefila.com/files/The_Theme_Of_The_Bracha_Of_Ha_Kail_Ha_Kadosh-2.pdf) (see last page of article, esp.) the main focus of the bracha הקל הקדוש is the concept of קבלת עול מלכות שמים  (acceptance of the yoke of G-d's kingdom). While this has already been done during the recital of *Shema*, the article explains that there are 2 type of קבלות. The one in *Shema* is regarding the past, and the one in *Shemoneh Esreh* is regarding Mashiach. He claims that the original them of the blessing הקל הקדוש represents the Messianci fervor that existed after the destruction of the 2nd Temple.

Comment: I have no idea what a קבלת עול מלכות שמים regarding the past is, nor what a קבלת עול מלכות שמים regarding _mashiach_ is. (I mean, I know what קבלת עול מלכות שמים is, I think, but don't understand how it can be with respect to the past or _mashiach_.) But maybe I'm alone in that.

Comment: @msh210 I didn't comment because I saw it got an upvote and was accepted so I assumed I just didn't get it. But I really don't understand what this means.

Comment: @msh210 Have you read the article? It seemed understandable to me, even if the terminology seems strange.

Comment: Nope. But — if feasible — an answer should be comprehensible per se.